# WebdriverIO - characters being stripped out of string

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

This may be a long shot but I'm seeing the weirdest thing. I'm using the `setValue` and `addValue` functions from WebdriverIO and whenever my string contains the number `3`, it is being stripped out and not entered into the input boxes. I am manually able to type `3` into these inputs so I have no idea what is going on. `3` is the only character I've seen this happen with.

Any ideas?

Update: This is only occurring in Chrome

Update 2: Sorry for the lack of details. Here is additional info. I'm using wdio test runner. This issue does not occur in Safari or Firefox, only in chrome.

`browser.setValue(usernameInput, "t3st")` will input "tst" into the usernameInput element. As well 
`browser.addValue(usernameInput, "t3st")`. Any string containing a 3 will be inputted to any element, but all 3's will be missing from the string.

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.24.0",
    "babel-register": "~6.26.0",
    "chai": "~4.1.2",
    "chromedriver": "^2.33.2",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "~1.0.2",
    "wdio-phantomjs-service": "~0.2.2",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "~0.0.9",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "~0.1.2",
    "webdriverio": "4.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "~21.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "~6.26.0",
    "eslint": "~4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "~12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.8.0",
    "forever": "~0.15.3",
    "http-server": "~0.10.0",
    "jest": "~21.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Well, like the people above correctly pointed out, you need to provide relevant debug info. I would add you should also post the following: **1.)** the `package.json` dependencies for your project; **2.)** the snippet of code will also help greatly (are you using the *WDIO test-runner*, or no?); **3.)** are you using the latest **[chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/)**?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I've added more information to the post.

Comment: I also encountered this with webdriver.io. It is inconsistent behavior,hence the difficultly in reproducing. I ended up with a helper function called safeInput that will loop on the value until it is the same as requested value. In tests that are running visually I can see this happen irregularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had a look, but didn't manage to reproduce it. I tried both of the bellow examples using different variants of `chromedriver`, or `wdio-selenium-standalone-service`. All worked just fine.

> My guess is that:

- maybe that input you're trying to fill in has some `JavaScript` logic behind (form-validation) which might be truncating digits;
- or, maybe you have some old software (outdated packages) from your `package.json` dependencies which you previously installed globally (`npm install -g <packageName>`) and forgot about;

**WebdriverIO** (`v4.8.0`):

```
> browser.setValue('*[connectqa-mya="first-name"]',"t3st t3st t3st 1234test")
{ state: 'pending' }
> [13:27:12]  COMMAND   POST     "/wd/hub/session/29096eb4bd851d6e3a49ad740c3c1ead/elements"
  [13:27:12]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":"*[connectqa-mya=\"first-name\"]"}
  [13:27:12]  RESULT              [{"ELEMENT":"0.8157706669622329-6"}]
  [13:27:12]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/29096eb4bd851d6e3a49ad740c3c1ead/element/0.8157706669622329-6/clear"
  [13:27:12]  DATA                {}
  [13:27:12]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/29096eb4bd851d6e3a49ad740c3c1ead/element/0.8157706669622329-6/value"
  [13:27:12]  DATA                {"value":["t","3","s","t"," ","t","3","s","t"," ","(13 more items)"],"text":"t3st t3st t3st 1234test"}
```

**WebdriverIO** (`v4.7.1`):

```
> browser.setValue('*[connectqa-mya="first-name"]',"t3st t3st test1234 @#$%^&*")
{ state: 'pending' }
> [13:38:25]  COMMAND   POST     "/wd/hub/session/3b621c3d7a774872cf3a37d1bec17014/elements"
  [13:38:25]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":"*[connectqa-mya=\"first-name\"]"}
  [13:38:25]  RESULT              [{"ELEMENT":"0.42949459661053613-6"}]
  [13:38:25]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/3b621c3d7a774872cf3a37d1bec17014/element/0.42949459661053613-6/clear"
  [13:38:25]  DATA                {}
  [13:38:25]  RESULT              undefined
  [13:38:25]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/3b621c3d7a774872cf3a37d1bec17014/element/0.42949459661053613-6/value"
  [13:38:25]  DATA                {"value":["t","3","s","t"," ","t","3","s","t"," ","(16 more items)"]}
```

> As next-steps in the debugging process I would:

- try to replicate the project with the same `dependencies` in a different folder/repo and see if it works;
- for the above approach I would start with the latest versions of the packages you're using (e.g.: WebdriverIO wasn't up to date);
- try to use `.execute("$('<selector>').val('t3st t3st test12345');")` and see if using **JavaScript**/**JQuery** would yield different results (if so, it would narrow down the problem: not form-validation, but probably `chromedriver`).

Let me know how it went, or if it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Today I tried installing different versions of webdriverIO and chromedriver to no avail. I replicated the project in different repos a few different ways and still get the issue in Chrome. I am going to keep looking at this and will let you know if I end up finding the issue.

Comment: After more debugging and recreating the project with different dependencies, I figured out that the project was using an older version of chromedriver. Despite version 2.33.2 being specified in package.json, it was using version 2.30. I'm still not sure how but I was able to recreate the project and have it use 2.33 and now the issue is gone. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @2bor02b I'm glad you made it work man! If you're using the `selenium-standalone` package you can actually avoid this in the future. It `cURL`s the latest drivers from each browser vendor. Just `npm install --save-dev selenium-standalone`, `selenium-standalone install` (this will always pull the latest builds, but you can overwrite them in case you don't want the latest builds). More on this on their **[page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone)**. Have a good one!